# GPO settings not applying for "check for server certificate revocation"

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

I am working in a disconnected environment with intranet sites.  When I open an SSL site it takes a good 2 minutes to open.  I did a wireshark to see what was happening and it is going out to a microsoft site.  Eventually it times out and the page loads. If I uncheck check for server certificate in the advanced settings in IE options the intranet sites load instantly.

I created a user GPO with these settings to push to all users in this environement. When they sign into the desktop they still get intranet sites that take a long time to load and in their IE settings the box is still checked even though via gpresult it says the policy is disabled.

If I do a gpupdate /force the check goes away in IE and the site loads immediately.

I don't know why it says the setting is disable in gpresult but not actually endabled in IE and why does it take a force to apply the policy.

Env is IE 11, Windows 10.  The users are signing into new machines.

Comment: IIRC, this option can be configured in  few different places in Group Policy. Are you using the one in `Internet Explorer Maintenance`, or the one in `Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer > Internet Control Panel > Advanced Page`?